# How to initialize a Party type in Corda?

Tags: block, blockchain, corda, ibm-blockchain

Recently I started with Corda and am a bit confused about this point.
I have a state which needs to initialize a party with some default values.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

> Actually I have a state which accepts a party as an argument. And I
>   want user to give the option to choose the party. so to define the
>   state's constructor I need to set it to some default value. Correct me
>   if I am wrong. I am new to Corda

I am answering this on based of your above comment.

Look into this example: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java

It's also storing `Party` in `State` and there is no default `Party` defined. It's accepting `Party` as `constructer` and assigning it to the class variable.

Comment: But the nuance here is, what if you don't want to give the party to the constructor, but want it created in the state's constructor? How do you ensure the party points to the correct node, the only way I can think of, is if you get the public key of the node you want to initialize... but how do you do that if your network is bootstrapped..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the definition of Party.kt in Corda and you'll see that a Party is constructed from an X509Certificate.

Could you elaborate on why you need to initialize a party with a default value? Parties should already be defined on the network and you can find obtain a reference to them by querying the networkMapCache.

In addition, you can fetch your own Party identity within flows by calling ourIdentity or using the serviceHub.

Comment: Actually I have a state which accepts a party as an argument. And I want user to give the option to choose the party. so to define the state's constructor I need to set it to some default value. 
Correct me if I am wrong. I am new to Corda